# How to find what caused onChange event for select box in IE - keyboard or mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, select, onchange

Is there some way to find out what caused the onChange event on select box in Internet Explorer (>= IE8) - keyboard or mouse?

I have a code which doing something when user selecting a value, and this code works great in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE (no surprise, huh). In IE it works fine only if user uses mouse but not a keyboard, because then it fires a onchange event on every keypress (not on Enter as normal browsers).

So, to fix this behavior I need to know if event is fired using a keyboard and then I will filter it.

**Update:**

Ok, after playing a bit I found a good solution. Posting it here in case someone will find it useful. Solution below using jQuery but it can be done in pure Javascript too.

This is a code which caused a problem:

```
$("#mySelectBox").change(function () {
    // Do something
});
```

And this is my solution. It's probably not perfect, but it works in my case. And event handlers could be chained in jQuery, of course. The code below stores initial value of the select and uses it to avoid doing something on initial mouse click - when user expands a select box. Also it filters all keypresses except Enter.

```
function doSomething(el) {
    if (el.data["valueOnFocused"] !== el.val()) {
        // Do something
    }
}

$("#mySelectBox").focusin(function () {
    $(this).data["valueOnFocused"] = $(this).val();
});

$("#mySelectBox").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13)
    {
        doSomething($(this));
    }
});

$("#mySelectBox").click(function () {
    doSomething($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the onchange event is *supposed* to be fired when the user makes a selection then leaves the input (be it select, textbox, radio button, whatever). Since this isn't working in IE, you could try using onblur instead, to detect when the user actually leaves the box. At that point you could read which item is selected and act accordingly. This is more of a workaround, but might do what you need.

Edit: another option would be to detect the pressing of the Enter key, like so:

```
if(e && e.which){ // NN4 specific code
e = e
characterCode = e.which
}
else {
e = event
characterCode = e.keyCode // IE specific code
}
```

The characterCode variable now has the "code" of which button was pressed. If it was the enter key, that code will be 13. You could listen for this.

Comment: Yes, I already tried onblur, but it's not equivalent replacement in my case, because it requires an extra step to leave a control which is not that obvious. And plus user see no immediate action which can be confusing too.

Comment: You could try detecting when the Enter key is pressed. I modified my answer to include that option.